# Bound for the magnitude of the determinant of a SDD matrix (Gerschgorin's Theorem)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I need to prove the following relationship, given that $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ is SDD (Strictly Diagonally Dominant):

$\prod_{i=1}^n \left( |a_{ii}| - \sum_{j \neq i} |a_{ij}| \right) \leq |\det(A) |$

Which is strongly related to Gerschgorin's Theorem. However, I can't manage to find a way to prove it. Any help will be much appreciated :).

Comment: Related: [Identical inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559796/questions-about-gerschgorin-circle-theorem).